# Implementing a recursive coin change function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm totally blocked with a recursive problem. It's one that other people have asked about, but nobody seems to have asked about it in JS that I can see (sorry if I've missed something!) and reading other answers isn't helping.

In any case, I have a recursive program that returns the minimum number of coins necessary:

```
function change(amount, coins){
    if (amount == 0){
        return 0;
    } else if (coins.length == 0 && amount > 0){
        return Infinity;
    } else if (coins[0] > amount){
        return change(amount, coins.slice(1));
    } else {
        var loseIt = 0 + change(amount, coins.slice(1));
        var useIt = 1 + change(amount - coins[0], coins);
        return Math.min(loseIt, useIt);
    }
}

change(48, [1, 5, 10, 25, 50])
>>> 6
change(48, [1, 7, 24, 42])
>>> 2
```

But when I try to modify it into returning not just the number of coins, but also the coins used, I keep exceeding the max number of stack calls or just crashing the console in Chrome.

**Answer should look like**:

```
change(48, [1, 5, 10, 25, 50])
>>> [6, [25, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1]]
change(48, [1, 7, 24, 42])
>>> [2, [24, 24]]
```

Here's my code:

```
function change(amount, coins){
    if (amount == 0){
        return [0,[]];
    } else if (coins.length == 0 && amount > 0){
        return [Infinity,[]];
    } else if (coins[0] > amount){
        return change(amount, coins.slice(1));
    } else {
        var loseIt = [change(amount, coins.slice(1))[0], [].concat(change(amount, coins.slice(1))[1])];
        var useIt = [1 + change(amount - coins[0], coins)[0], [coins[0]].concat(change(amount - coins[0], coins)[1])];
        if (useIt[0] > loseIt[0]){
            return loseIt;
        } else {
            return useIt;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that it should *always* be returning an array with the coin count and coins array. I stepped through the function and it appears to be returning the right answers, but it doesn't stop running.

I have a feeling it rests in the loseIt/useIt definitions, but when I test something like

```
[x[0] + y[0], x[1].concat(y[1])]
```

where `x` and `y` are arrays formatted like the ones I'm returning in my function, it seems to return the right format all the way through.

I'm self-teaching this stuff, so no lab or TA to help me out - hoping someone can explain what I'm doing incorrectly here!

Comment: What values are valid for *amount*, and what values are in the *coins* array?

Comment: I had a suspicion I'd forget something like that on my first SO question. I've edited the question above to include an example of the function call and expected results. @RobG

Comment: Thanks, it's clearer now. ;-)

Comment: The accepted answer is nice but it's also very inefficient. You may like to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383423/4543207) answer for a much more efficient algorithm along with their comparison. Even though it returns all possible coins, filtering the shortest one should be a trivial job either within the algorithm or after by a filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem

```
var loseIt = [
    change(amount, coins.slice(1))[0], [].concat(
    change(amount, coins.slice(1))[1])];
var useIt = [1 + 
    change(amount - coins[0], coins)[0], [coins[0]].concat(
    change(amount - coins[0], coins)[1])];
```

vs working

```
var loseIt = 0 + change(amount, coins.slice(1));
var useIt = 1 + change(amount - coins[0], coins);
```

As you see, the call of `change()` is done once for `loseIt` and `useIt`. In the version for array with the coin count, the function `change()` is called twice with the same parameter, but here you need the array elements of the return value of the function.

Solution:

Basically the same as in the count only version. One call of `change()` for `loseIt` and `useIt`. Later you can use the array for further processing.

```js
function change(amount, coins) {
    if (amount === 0) {
        return [0, []];
    }
    if (coins.length === 0 && amount > 0) {
        return [Infinity, []];
    }
    if (coins[0] > amount) {
        return change(amount, coins.slice(1));
    } else {
        var loseIt = change(amount, coins.slice(1));  // just one call of change
        var useIt = change(amount - coins[0], coins); // just one call of change
        if (loseIt[0] < 1 + useIt[0]) {
            return loseIt;
        } else {
            return [1 + useIt[0], useIt[1].concat(coins[0])];
        }
    }
}

console.log(change(12, [9, 6, 1]));                   // [2, [6, 6]]
console.log(change(48, [1, 5, 10, 25, 50]));          // [6, [25, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1]]
console.log(change(48, [1, 7, 24, 42]));              // [2, [24, 24]]
console.log(change(189, [1, 77, 17, 63, 92, 8, 14])); // [3, [63, 63, 63]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems relatively obvious now that the problem was the double call of `change()`, because at the time I didn't realize that calling loseIt doesn't require a return of any sort of coins — only useIt needs to do so, even if the loseIt call returns a useIt down the line.