# Algorithm for calculating number of fitting boxes

Tags: php, algorithm, equation, algebra

I've a client selling wine bottles. He uses boxes with space for 6 bottles, 12 bottles, 18 bottles and 21 bottles. But he only wants to accept orders which fit exactly into these boxes. There must not be any empty space inside.

E.g.

- 33 is ok: 1x21 and 2x6
- 48 is ok: 2x21 and 1x6 or 4x12
- 26 or 35 or 61 are not ok

For my first try was an straight simple way. I produce an array containing a lot of valid numbers, remove duplicates and order them.

```
$numbers = [];
$end = (int) $bottles/6 + 1;
for ($i=1; $i<=$end; $i++) {      
  $numbers[] = $i * 6;
  $numbers[] = $i * 21;
  $numbers[] = $i * 21 + 6;
  $numbers[] = $i * 21 + 6 + 6;
  $numbers[] = $i * 21 + 6 + 6 + 6;
}
$numbers = array_unique($numbers);
sort($numbers);
```

It looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 18
    [3] => 21
    [4] => 24
    [5] => 27
    [6] => 30
    [7] => 33
    [8] => 36
    [9] => 39
    [10] => 42
    [11] => 48
    [12] => 54
    [13] => 60
    [14] => 63
    ....
```

I can check against my list. ok, fine!

But I want to make a "perfekt" solution fitting for all possible numbers, e.g. I want to know if 123456 is possible. You see, that the array must be very huge for getting this :-)

I tried an equation with 2 unknowns. Why only 2? Because 18 and 12 can be divided by 6. So my approch was:

```
bottles = 6a + 21b
```

"a" and "b" must be integer values and may contain zero. "bottles" is an integer value, too. I transformed it to:

```
 bottles / 6 - 3,5b = a
```

But this doesn't help me to make a good algorithm... I think I'm on the right way, but how can I solve this quite elegant? Where are the algebra gurus? ;-)

Comment: This is equivalent to the coin change problem. But your numbers are so simple, that it is very easy: x % 6 == 0 or (x % 3 == 0 and x >= 21)

Comment: @maraca: This code seems to be perfect... just for my understanding: 3 ist the smallest common factor of 6 and 21 or how did you get this value?

Comment: As a follow-up and just for fun, you could try the minimum boxes required to fill all the bottles and print the sequence of them.

Comment: @vivek_23 I think I found the code that does that.

Comment: @Marco that is exactly the idea behind the solution as you can write `gcd(a,b) = a*x - b*y` with x and y natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I found @vivek_23's comment challenging so I figured I would give it a try.

This code will optimize the amount to the smallest number of boxes to fill the order.

It does so by first trying with 21 boxes and if the result is not %6 then it will loop backwards to if it gets a sum that is %6 and split up the rest.

```
// 99 is challenging since 99 can be divided on 21 to 4, but the remainder is not % 6 (15).
// However the remainder 15 + 21 = 36 which is % 6. 
// Meaning the "correct" output should be 3 x 21 + 2 x 18 = 99
$order = 99;
$b = [21 => 0, 18 => 0, 12 => 0, 6 => 0];

// number of 21 boxes possible
if($order >= 21){
    $b[21] = floor($order/21);
    $order -= $b[21]*21;
}

// if the remainder needs to be modified to be divisible on 6
while($order % 6 != 0){
    if($b[21] > 0){
        // remove one box of 21 and add the bottles back to the remainder
        $order += 21;
        $b[21]--;
    }else{
        // if we run out of 21 boxes then the order is not possible.
        echo "order not possible";
        exit;
    }
}
// split up the remainder on 18/12/6 boxes and remove empty boxes 
$b = array_filter(split_up($b, $order));

var_dump($b);

function split_up($b, $order){
    // number of 18 boxes possible
    if($order >= 18){
        $b[18] = floor($order/18);
        $order -= $b[18]*18;
    }
    // number of 12 boxes possible
    if($order >= 12){
        $b[12] = floor($order/12);
        $order -= $b[12]*12;
    }
    // number of 6 boxes possible
    if($order >= 6){
        $b[6] = floor($order/6);
        $order -= $b[6]*6;
    }
    return $b;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/EM9EF

Comment: Not tested thoroughly, but works well with a few tests I made. +1.

Comment: Ok, tested thoroughly and this works well. I made a solution using dynamic programming which is like coin change problem. Mine just returns the minimum boxes for now where in I could further store what type of boxes. But for the sake of testing, I just compared my min boxes with yours and it seems to be correct. Mine uses O(n) extra space which makes it a bit slow on multiple tests, but both indeed produce the same output. Cheers :) **Demo:** https://3v4l.org/9ZEpQ

Comment: @vivek_23 interesting approach. I have a hard time reading it now since I'm using my phone but when I get back to a computer I will have a look at it better

Comment: @vivek_23 Ok.. It's nice but you made one big mistake `for($i=1;$i<=2500;++$i){`  should be `for($i=2500;$i>=1;--$i){`. You always count bottles down. That way you can sing along with the code "2500 bottles of wine on the wall, 2500 bottles of wine, take one down...". I see what you mean with it being slow creating those arrays and all the looping.

Comment: Haha, good one :) You mean [this song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/99_Bottles_of_Beer) ?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on maraca's comment, we're trying to solve the equation x = 6a + 21b over nonnegative integers. Since 6 and 21 are divisible by 3 (the greatest common divisor of 6 and 21), it is necessary that x is divisible by 3. Moreover, if x is less than 21, then it is necessary that x is divisible by 6.

Conversely, if x is divisible by 6, we can set a = x/6 and b = 0. If x is an odd multiple of 3, then x - 21 is divisible by 6; if x is at least 21, we can set a = (x - 21)/6 and b = 1. Every multiple of 3 is either odd or even (and hence divisible by 6), so this proves maraca's equivalence claim.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce this homework to some simpler logic with 3 valid cases:

1. Multiples of 21.
2. Multiples of 6.
3. A combination of the above.

Eg:

```
function divide_order($q) {
    $result['total'] = $q;
    // find the largest multiple of 21 whose remainder is divisible by 6
    for( $i=intdiv($q,21); $i>=0; $i-- ) {
        if( ($q - $i * 21) % 6 == 0 ) {
            $result += [
                'q_21' => $i,
                'q_6' => ( $q - $i * 21 ) / 6
            ];
            break;
        }
    }
    if( count($result) == 1 ) {
        $result['err'] = true;
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(
    array_map('divide_order', [99, 123456])
);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["total"]=>
    int(99)
    ["q_21"]=>
    int(3)
    ["q_6"]=>
    int(6)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["total"]=>
    int(123456)
    ["q_21"]=>
    int(5878)
    ["q_6"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

Then you can apply some simple logic to reduce multiple boxes of 6 into boxes of 12 or 18.

Comment: With 123456 as input you get 20576 boxes of 6 from your code. Even if you make 3 boxes of 6 to one 18 box it still completly leave out 21 boxes.

Comment: @Andreas nice catch. I popped the "21 and 6" up to the start of the logic and it's a much more reasonable 21 x 5878 and 3 x 6 now. Did you know that 123456 factored neatly for this, or was that just a happy coincidence?

Comment: That was from the question. ***I want to know if 123456 is possible.*** I don't think it was litteral but why not try it...

Comment: Your code return error on 99 https://3v4l.org/Pm87B ( 3 x 21 + 2 x 18 = 99)

Comment: 99 can also be 4 x 18 + 21 + 6

Comment: @Andreas you've defeated me. I must concede that a loop is necessary. We could also add a clause that if the quatity is not divisible by 3 it is not packable at all by definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
function winePacking(int $bottles): bool {
    return ($bottles % 6 == 0 || ($bottles % 21) % 3 == 0);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/bTQHe

Logic Behind the code:

You're working with simple numbers, 6,12,18 can all be covered by mod 6, being that 6 goes into all 3 of those numbers. 21 we can just check a mod 21, and if it's somewhere in between then it's mod 21 mod 6.

Simple as that with those numbers.

Comment: I checked this code with 87... it produces false, but should be ok: 87 = 21 + 21 + 21 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6

Comment: @Marco sorry that was my screw up, I made a typo on a number, try again.

Comment: @vivek_23 most likely 3 also then.

Comment: @Andreas yes, it would give true for 3 as well.

Comment: if you do the alogorithm like maraca ion the first comment avobe, it will work: `function winePacking(int $bottles) {
    return ($bottles % 6 == 0 || ($bottles >=21 && $bottles % 3 == 0));
}`

Answer (score 0):

What if you do something like so:

```
function boxes($number) {

    if($number >= 21) {

        $boxesOfTwentyOne = intval($number / 21);
        $remainderOfTwetyOne = floor($number % 21);

        if($remainderOfTwetyOne === 0.0) {

            return $boxesOfTwentyOne . ' box(es) of 21';

        }

        $boxesOfTwentyOne = $boxesOfTwentyOne - 1;

        $number >= 42 ? $textTwentyOne = $boxesOfTwentyOne . ' boxes of 21, ' : $textTwentyOne = '1 box of 21, ';

        $sixesBoxes = floor($number % 21) + 21;

        switch (true) {
            case ($sixesBoxes == 24):
                if($number >= 42) {
                    return $textTwentyOne . '1 box of 18 and 1 box of 6';
                }
                return '1 box of 18 and 1 box of 6';
            break;

            case ($sixesBoxes == 27):
                return $boxesOfTwentyOne + 1 . ' box(es) of 21 and 1 box of 6';
            break;

            case ($sixesBoxes == 30):
                if($number >= 42) {
                    return $textTwentyOne . '1 box of 18 and 1 box of 12';
                }
                return '1 box of 18 and 1 box of 12';
            break;

            case ($sixesBoxes == 33):
                return $boxesOfTwentyOne + 1 . ' box(es) of 21 and 1 box of 12';
            break;

            case ($sixesBoxes == 36):
                if($number >= 42) {
                    return $textTwentyOne . '2 boxes of 18';
                }
                return '2 boxes of 18';
            break;

            case ($sixesBoxes == 39):
                return $boxesOfTwentyOne + 1 . ' box(es) of 21 and 1 box of 18';
            break;

            default:
                return 'Not possible!';
            break;
        }

    } else {

       switch (true) {
            case ($number == 6):
                return '1 box of 6';
            break;
            case ($number == 12):
                return '1 box of 12';
            break;
            case ($number == 18):
                return '1 box of 18';
            break;
            default:
                return 'Not possible!';
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

EDIT: I have updated my answer, and now I think it is working properly. At least, it passed in all the tests I've made here.

Comment: Isn't that the answer you are looking for? What should be the return of 24?

Comment: @LucasArbex  18+6=24

Comment: Ohhh, ok. I got it now. Gonna try to refactor ir then. :)

Comment: @Marco if you are still looking for an answer, please check if this can help you now. :)

Comment: I have found two cases that doesn't work. 123456 returns null, and 50 by some reason returns incorrect. https://3v4l.org/G2Vhf

Comment: @Andreas indeed 123456 returns null, i don't know why. On the other hand, shouldn't it be "2 boxes of 21 and 1 box of 6" on 50? I know that some bottles will be left out, but this is the better set up of boxes if you have 50 bottles, correct?

Comment: Two boxes of 21 = 42. Plus 6 = 48, not 50.

Comment: @Andreas exactly, that is my point. If the user types 50, he should get the best option for him, that is 48 with "2 boxes of 21 and 1 box of 6", correct? All my algorithm was made with that assumption... 49 should return the same result, however 51 (or 52 or 53) should return "1 box of 21, 1 box of 18 and 1 box of 6"... and so on

Comment: But that is not what the question asks for.

Comment: @Andreas indeed, my mistake! But it is a simple fix. Just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually array items summing up to a target where repetition is allowed problem.

Since in many cases multiple box configurations will come up, you may chose to use the shortest boxes sub list or may be the boxes sublist with the available boxes at hand in real life.

Sorry my PHP is rusty... the below algorithm is in JS but you may simply adapt it to PHP. Of course you may freely change your box sizes to accomodate any number of bottles. So for the given boxes and target 87 we get in total 20 different solutions like

```
[12,18,18,18,21], [12,12,21,21,21] ... [6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,21]
```

```js
function items2T([n,...ns],t){cnt++ //remove cnt in production code
    var c = ~~(t/n);
    return ns.length ? Array(c+1).fill()
                                 .reduce((r,_,i) => r.concat(items2T(ns, t-n*i).map(s => Array(i).fill(n).concat(s))),[])
                     : t % n ? []
                             : [Array(c).fill(n)];
};

var cnt = 0, result;
console.time("combos");
result = items2T([6,12,18,21], 87)
console.timeEnd("combos");
console.log(result);
console.log(`${result.length} many unique ways to sum up to 87
and ${cnt} recursive calls are performed`);
```

The code is taken from [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383423/4543207).