# How to count all numeric array elements combinations whose sum is equal to a given value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The question is in the title.
As an example:

Given this `array = [1,1,2,2,3,7,9,1]` and `sum = 7`, I expect this result:

```
1,1,2,2,1
1,1,2,3
...
7
```

A quadratic time answer is trivial, I am looking for a sub-quadratic-time solution...
My current sloooow solution:

```js
function subsetSum(numbers, target, partial) {
  var s, n, remaining;

  partial = partial || [];

  // sum partial
  s = partial.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);

  // check if the partial sum is equals to target
  if (s === target) {
    console.log(partial.join(","))
  }

  if (s >= target) {
    return; // if we reach the number we don't bother to continue
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    n = numbers[i];
    remaining = numbers.slice(i + 1);
    subsetSum(remaining, target, partial.concat([n]));
  }
}

subsetSum([1,1,2,2,3,7,9,1], 7);
```

Output:

```
1,1,2,2,1
1,1,2,3
1,1,2,3
1,2,3,1
1,2,3,1
1,2,3,1
1,2,3,1
2,2,3
7
```

For 2k 1-digit numbers, after 4 minutes of crunching, in my box nodejs (v11.14.0) spits out:

*FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory*

:-(

Comment: please add your answer. what is wrong with it? it looks like a subset sum problem.

Comment: It is too slow!

Comment: You need to include it anyway, not least so people know what you're saying you *don't* want.

Comment: For folks who ain't got no larnin' (like me): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Sub-quadratic_time

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum See also https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_the_coins

Comment: It is too slow, however I will add it here, hoping I can clarify what I do mean...

Comment: I added a snippet with my current solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find possible numbers in array that can sum to a target value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605306/find-possible-numbers-in-array-that-can-sum-to-a-target-value)

Comment: Check [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383423/4543207) that I have given above against your test case array with 146 items. Just filter out the items above the target value (7) and **do not** sort your list (as advised in my answer) either ascending or descending and it will solve your 146 items test case for target 7 in about 4:21 in my humble AMD PC returning 4,259,351 solutions. No memory clogging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a recursive call by avoiding built in array methods (iteration and most expensive slicing) and take a recursive function which get an index for the next number to get, an array of collected values and a new target, without the last taken value.

This approach returns all possible values, they are not unique, depending on the given data. This approach works for positive numbers only.

```js
function subsetSum(numbers, target) {
    function iter(index, right, delta) {
        if (!delta) return result.push(right);
        if (index >= numbers.length) return;
        if (delta - numbers[index] >= 0)
            iter(index + 1, [...right, numbers[index]], delta - numbers[index]);
        iter(index + 1, right, delta);
    }
    var result = [];
    iter(0, [], target);
    return result;
}

subsetSum([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 7, 9, 1], 7).map(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Clever solution. Though, even with only 150 one-digit numbers, Javascript heap is out of memory, on my box... :-(

Comment: have you eliminated to large values, or too much small same numbers?

Comment: I don't get you, sorry... My test numbers are: [6,7,2,5,8,0,1,3,6,3,2,8,7,9,1,5,7,5,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4,1,2,2,3,7,9,4]. They are 146, so I can run the algorithm without memory errors...

Comment: you could filter all values greater than the wanted sum, and eliminates smaller values which sum is greater than the wanted sum.

Comment: Yes, thanks... That should be an improvement... But I'm looking for a FASTER and LESS MEMORY CONSUMING solution, if it exists...