# Generate unique combinations in JavaScript from n objects with r samples

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

What is the best way to generate all unique combinations in JavaScript from N objects with R samples. For example:

```
n = [100,200,300,400]
r = 3
```

Expected result

```
    [100,200,300]
    [100,200,400]
    [200,300,400]
    [100,300,400]
```

I am able to achieve above using **recursive solution**. But it is slow for large datasets (e.g. `N=25, R=10`). Is there any faster way to achieve this?

Comment: "large datasets" - how large? Could you give us some realistic values for your N and R?

Comment: @georg    Typically N is 25 and R is 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here a straight implementation of a sequential generator as described in Wikipedia:

> ...track k index numbers of the elements selected, starting with {0 .. k−1} (zero-based) or {1 .. k} (one-based) as the first allowed k-combination and then repeatedly moving to the next allowed k-combination by incrementing the last index number if it is lower than n-1 (zero-based) or n (one-based) or the last index number x that is less than the index number following it minus one if such an index exists and resetting the index numbers after x to {x+1, x+2, …}.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Enumerating_k-combinations

```js
function combinations(a, c) {
    let index = []
    let n = a.length

    for (let j = 0; j < c; j++)
        index[j] = j
    index[c] = n

    let ok = true
    let result = []

    while (ok) {

        let comb = []
        for (let j = 0; j < c; j++)
            comb[j] = a[index[j]]
        result.push(comb)

        ok = false

        for (let j = c; j > 0; j--) {
            if (index[j - 1] < index[j] - 1) {
                index[j - 1]++
                for (let k = j; k < c; k++)
                    index[k] = index[k - 1] + 1
                ok = true
                break
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}

//

N = 25
R = 10
A = Array(N).fill(0).map((_, n) => n)

console.time()
combs = combinations(A, R)
console.log(combs.length, 'combinations')
console.timeEnd()
```

Takes < 1 sec on my machine.

Comment: Perfect :) It reduced 3/4th of time of recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The following recursive code should be efficient. You can perhaps make it mode efficient in JS if you rephrase it into imperative loops etc.

C 17/10 is done @30ms on an old AMD Phenom 1090T whereas C25/10 takes about 1500ms.

```js
function getCombinations(a,n,s=[],t=[]){
  return a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => ( n > 1 ? getCombinations(a.slice(i+1), n-1, p, (t.push(c),t))
                                       : p.push((t.push(c),t).slice(0))
                               , t.pop()
                               , p
                               ),s)
}

var a = Array.from({length:25}, (_,i) => i),
    n = 10,
    c;
console.time("cs");
c = getCombinations(a,n);
console.timeEnd("cs");
console.log(c.length);
```

Comment: very nice, I didn't expect a recursive solution having performance similar to straight loops.

Comment: @georg [This was](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383423/4543207) my **WHAT!?!** moment in JS recursions. In some rare cases they are super handy.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>With the help of a hash-table to store all "already visited combinations" in order to avoid recursing multiple times through them, I managed to optimize the recursive algorith to calculate R=10 for a N of size 17 in ~44 seconds.</strike>

The problem is that the number of combinations grows by a factorial margin. With N 25 and R 10 we are already looking at something like 15! combinations, which is quite large (1.3076744e+12).

You might have an easier time implementing the algorithm in a faster language/system and delegating computation there.

```js
const N = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700];

const R = 10;

const hash = (arr) => arr.join('-');

const solutions = [];
const visitedHashes = {};

const uniqueCombos = (n, r) => {
  const nHash = hash(n);
  if (visitedHashes[nHash]) {
    return;
  }
  visitedHashes[nHash] = true;
  
  if (n.length < r) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    if (n.length === r) {
      solutions.push(n);
    }
    n.forEach(element => uniqueCombos(n.filter(el => el !== element), r));
  }
}

const start = Date.now();
uniqueCombos(N, R);
const time = Date.now() - start;
console.log(`${solutions.length} combinations calculated in ${time} milliseconds`);
```

**EDIT 2: As per Yoshi's comment-suggestion, using a lookup object instead of an array for `visitedHashes` reduced time significantly.**

Comment: If it's combinations without repetition (which I assume), it isn't all that bad actually. For (25/10) it's *only* 3,268,760 combinations. This being said, your algorithm could be drastically improved by making `visitedHashes` a `Set` (or simple object). Doing so, gives me 296ms instead of 32072ms on my local machine.

Comment: Could you add test code for N=25, R=10, for comparison?

Comment: Sorry this solution decreased the performance.

Comment: @georg good idea, I switched to 25, 10. But please dont try to run it, takes too long :D. My solution is the least efficient in here but I will leave it hanging around for benchmarking and to better highlight what the other solutions are doing better in contrast.
DevAnanth it might be interesting if you add your initial solution as an answer (or add it to the question)