# How to produce all possible teams from a list of players?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a list ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

We can imagine each letter as a player. The goal is to produce all possible teams of 3. In this case the **desired output** would be...

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'd']
['a', 'c', 'd']
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

Atleast I think this is all possible combinations, correct me if I am wrong.

I wrote this but does not produce the desired input. If I remove the `data[j+1]` line and expect results for a team of 2 instead of 3 it works which is interesting.

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  for(let j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++){
    team = [data[i], data[j], data[j+1]]
  }
}
```

**How can I produce the desired output?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71997980/how-to-get-all-possible-3-element-combinations-from-an-array-of-n-elements-in-ja

Comment: or [combinations of size N from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075180/combinations-of-size-n-from-an-array) or [Generate unique combinations in JavaScript from n objects with r samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67720548/generate-unique-combinations-in-javascript-from-n-objects-with-r-samples) or [How to get all the combinations for an array of a specific length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67411935/how-to-get-all-the-combinations-for-an-array-of-a-specific-length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a third loop layer.

```js
function allTeamsOf3(arr) {
  let res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
      for (let k = j + 1; k < arr.length; k++)
        res.push([arr[i], arr[j], arr[k]]);
  return res;
}
console.log(allTeamsOf3(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
```

Recursion can be used for a more general solution.

```js
function allTeams(arr, size) {
  let res = [];
  function helper(curr, i) {
    if (curr.length === size) res.push([...curr]);
    else if (i < arr.length) {
      helper(curr.concat(arr[i]), i + 1);
      helper(curr, i + 1);
    }
  }
  helper([], 0);
  return res;
}
console.log(allTeams(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the recursive approach to find the combination from an array of string.

```js
function uniqueCombinations(names, groupSize = 3, index = 0, current = []) {
    if (current.length === groupSize) return [current];
    if (index === names.length) return [];
    return uniqueCombinations(names, groupSize, index + 1, current.concat(names[index]))
        .concat(uniqueCombinations(names, groupSize, index + 1, current));
}

const names = ['Arlong', 'Blackbeard', 'Chopper', 'Doma', 'Eman'];
const result = uniqueCombinations(names);
console.log( { result, length: result.length } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am just thinking of a more mathematical way to explain it if learner wanna understand more.

Assume that your "combinations" are not repeating. We know the number of solutions is strictly `nCr`. Which `n` is the size of your set and `r` is the size of the subset.

In Math, we can present it in sets.
For a random set I can make up rn `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7` :)

What we want is to avoid repeating combinations.
One of the easy way to do it is via a sorting algorithm.

As an example, for a subset size of 3. we already got `0 1 (2/3/4/5/6/7)`.
The next round will be `0 2 (3/4/5/6/7)`

That the selection set `(3/4/5/6/7)` are greater than the last chosen `2`. So it eliminates the chance of getting `0 2 1`

As long as you keep the data set in `order`(Which is ordered with your decision), you can pretty much solve it with any technique (recursive, loops, or even repeatedly push and pop a container). The guys demonstrated some of the recursive implementations for the problem.

Alternatively...

About the harder math way to do it... I am not 100% sure how to do it. But I think it would be interesting to share.

Note that the presence of an element can be considered a binary state.
Which makes `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7` `11111111`. Then `0 1 2` would be `11100000`.

That makes it potentially possible to have a mapping function. With inputs `n r i`, we would be able to find the `i th` combination given in the recursive.

The reason I suggest this is that... `nCr` could have exponential growth. With `n=100,r=50` you already have a super large number. Which isn't very helpful.

With this mapping function(possibly using hash?), you could present `100C50` combinations with... An array size of "100", a "search" bitset with 100 bits.
Fantastic!